# inet_pton() gives "Segmentation fault"

Tags: c, sockets, networking

In my program, I am using the `inet_pton` function one of two ways:

First: Default IP if none is specified in argument.

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, defaultIP, &servaddr.sin_addr)
```

Second: When a command line IP address is given.

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr)
```

The problem is, the first one gives me a Segmentation fault, and the second one does not. I have a feeling it has to do with how I pass in the default IP but I can not quite figure it out. I defined defaultIP like this:

```
const char *defaultIP = "127.0.0.1";
```

I have tried many variations of passing in the IP address with no success. Perhaps this is not even the issue? However, if I pass in 127.0.0.1 at the command line, It works fine passing in through argv. Thanks in advance for any replies!

The entirety of the code I am working with is now here, as requested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SA struct sockaddr
#define MAXLINE     4096

void err_sys(const char*);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    const char *defaultIP = "127.0.0.1";
    int                 sockfd, n;
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr;
    char defaultAddr = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
        defaultAddr = 1;

    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        err_sys("socket error");

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port   = htons(13);    /* daytime server */

    if (defaultAddr = 1)
        if (inet_pton(AF_INET, defaultIP, &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
            err_sys("inet_pton error for input IP address");
    else
        if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
            err_sys("inet_pton error for input IP address");

    if (connect(sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
        err_sys("connect error");

    while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        recvline[n] = 0;    /* null terminate */
        if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF)
            err_sys("fputs error");
    }
    if (n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");

    exit(0);
}

void err_sys(const char* x) 
{ 
    perror(x); 
    exit(1); 
}
```

Comment: The difference is that `argv[1]` is a modifiable string and `"127.0.0.1"` is not, so if `inet_pton()` tries to modify the second argument, the segmentation fault is plausible.  I'm not convinced, though, that is the source of the trouble. … And, having checked the definition at [`inet_pton()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_pton.html), I'm sure that's not the problem: the second argument is a `const char *`.

Comment: Can you post a short complete example using the string literal which demonstrates the failure? There's a fairly chance the problem is something altogether unrelated to this difference.

Comment: Alright, I have added my code. Source from the Unix Network Programming book with my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two bugs here:

```
if (defaultAddr = 1)
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, defaultIP, &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
        err_sys("inet_pton error for input IP address");
else
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
        err_sys("inet_pton error for input IP address");
```

First you've got `=` where you intend `==`.  Second, your `else` is improperly indented for the code as written, or you've forgotten to use braces where they're necessary:

```
if (defaultAddr == 1)
{
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, defaultIP, &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
        err_sys("inet_pton error for input IP address");
}
else
{
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
        err_sys("inet_pton error for input IP address");
}
```

I didn't have to try very hard to spot the errors:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror inet_pton.c -o inet_pton
inet_pton.c: In function ‘main’:
inet_pton.c:32:5: error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]
     if (defaultAddr = 1)
     ^
inet_pton.c:32:8: error: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     if (defaultAddr = 1)
        ^
inet_pton.c:42:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘read’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

From GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks.

As corrected, I get the output (no argument, so using the default IP address):

```
connect error: Connection refused
```

which is reasonable, I think — I don't have a `daytime` server running on my machine.

Comment: Of course, it was something incredibly simple. Guess I should spend less time with Python! Literally went right over my head. Thanks for your assistance, and sorry it was so simple. xD

Comment: Help yourself by using at least most of the options I showed. We all make similar mistakes at times, but make sure your compiler gives you the maximum help it can.